# Why do i keep getting "false" for a bad bracketed expression in my Queue method?

Tags: java

Hey guys i am trying to use Queue to check for a good bracket and a bad bracket but i am having some problems with the bad brackets.
example:

```
1.. good bracketed expression
"a*[a+12]",
"a+(b)-c",
"a+{b+8+(b+c)}/a"

2..Bad bracketed expressions
"[", "(}",
 "a)[]", 
"([)]"--> i keep getting true for this instead of false.
 "]["
```

Here is the code && thanks for the support:

```
 private static boolean check(String string){
        Queue<Character> chars = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Character charr: string.toCharArray()){
            if (charr.equals('{') || charr.equals('[') || charr.equals('(')){
                chars.add(charr);
            }else if (charr.equals('}')){
                return (chars.contains('{') && chars.poll().equals('{'));
            }else if (charr.equals(')')){
                return (chars.contains('(') && chars.poll().equals('('));
            }else if (charr.equals(']')){
                return (chars.contains('[') && chars.poll().equals('['));
            }
        }
        return chars.isEmpty();
    }
```

Comment: You must read [ask].

Comment: You did not ask a question, you made a statement regarding your inability using Queue. Go back and edit your post and ask a real question.

Comment: For this kind of job using Stack is more meaningful than using a Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you poll the *first* element and don't check if the bracket is at the last position, you just check if it is in the array. Use `getLast()` to check if the open bracket is at the last position and `pollLast()` to remove the last element.

And don't return something inside the for loop. Just return the result at the end of your function. Your function validate `"([)]"` as true because it returns after `)` and doesn't process more.

```
private static boolean check(String string){
        Queue<Character> chars = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Character charr: string.toCharArray()){
            if (charr.equals('{') || charr.equals('[') || charr.equals('(')){
                chars.add(charr);
            }else if (charr.equals('}') && chars.getLast().equals('{')){
                chars.pollLast();
            }else if (charr.equals(')') && chars.getLast().equals('(')){
                chars.pollLast();
            }else if (charr.equals(']') && chars.getLast().equals('[')){
                chars.pollLast();
            }
        }
        return chars.isEmpty();
    }
```